# Achievements not being displayed in Play Games app

Tags: android, google-play-games

I've linked my app successfully and leaderboards work. I even submitted my score and checked rank. However achievements arent working.

I have 6 achievements added in play console, and copy-pasted all the id's into my `strings.xml`. And whenever I unlock an achievement I call

`mAchievementsClient.unlock(context.getString(R.string.achievement_name))`

But none of the achievements ever unlock.

Even in the Play Games app, no achievements are listed even though it's in the same Game Service that my working leaderboard is in. This game service is still in draft mode.

All the achievements are the correct id's, i made sure to copy-paste. What is the problem?

**EDIT**: Achievements are now being unlocked for some reason. However, the Play Games app still doesnt show any achievements.

Comment: I am the same problem like you. It concerns an application I am building and also other applications installed on my device.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct phone
{
    char name[50];
    char address[20];
    long  number;
}x[50];
```

//All Rights Reserve

Comment: Did you bring up the Achivements UI by using startActivityforResult as mentioned in [Displaying achievements](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements#displaying_achievements)?